How do I restart kernel programmatically?
Due to memory buildup issues, I need to re-start kernel, keeping/reloading one variable and continue calculation.
Say, I have a variable tst={1,2,3} and I want to keep it after restart.
I could Export it to a file, then Quit[], then Import it back. But, that's the manual way: no command will be executed after Quit[], so I’ll have to run evaluation after
Quit[] manually.
Is there a better, programmatical way to do this, preferrably avoiding exporting and importing data to and from disk?

There was a trick to make variables persistent over kernel restarts via a Dynamic object, but I'm on the mobile now and don't quite remember the details. Perhaps that helps to get you started.

@HansOlo Interesting. Do you recall a trick to continue evaluation after Quit[] ?

Related: How to automatically do a computation, Quit, restart and do a new computation

Since version 12.3 you have PersistentSymbol. Wolfram Research (2021), PersistentSymbol, Wolfram Language function, https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PersistentSymbol.html.

I've studied the links in coments, tested diff ways to start a new kernel and the PersistentSymbol. Ended up with export to file > CleanSlate > importitng from file. 1) making a calculation in new kernel does not reduce memory usage at all, and KernelEvaluate[] methods don't execute Quit[] or Exit[]; 2) exporting and importing back is much faster (3x in my case) than storing in PersistentSymbol and retrieving back from it.

Have you tried reducing the size of $HistoryLength? Try $HistoryLength = 10 at the start of your session.

@Edmund yes, i've set it straight to 1.
